# Bootstrap 3 Flexbox modification not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I have a site built on Bootstrap 3. I've created a custom row class to add flexbox to the layout but it doesn't seem to work correctly in Safari.

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
  .row-eq-height > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      This should be on the left
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      This should be on the right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Looks like it could be the pseudo elements that bootstrap is adding as a clearfix. Changing them to display block seems to fix the issue, not sure why though.

Comment: Hmmm nice catch, do you think it would cause any issues if I were to change those pseudo elements to `display:block` when they exist within my `row-eq-height` class?

Comment: Im pretty sure you'll be good. This example says that display:block is actually preferred... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/what-methods-of-clearfix-can-i-use/1633170#1633170

Comment: Actually now that I read it again, it says that with flexbox you don't need the clearfix. So I bet you can remove it all together.

Comment: @jleggio awesome, thank you so much for looking into that for me. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: First off, mixing Bootstrap 3 and Flexbox is a bad idea. Ver. 3 is based on `float` and doesn't work well with flex. Second, no meaning to prefix `display: *-flex` when you don't use prefixed versions for `flex-wrap: wrap;`. I strongly recommend you move to Bootstrap 4

Comment: @LGSon I appreciate the suggestion, but this project is way too big to move to Bootstrap 4. The `flex` adaptation is working perfectly fine. The code above overrides the floats.

Comment: No, that code does not override float, it adds `flex`. To remove float you need to do `float: none`. And do note, no point to use prefixed `display: *-flex` when you don't prefix the other flex properties.

Comment: @LGSon what i mean is that when the rows are set to `display:flex;` the floats are ignored. This is a widely used flex adaption for Bootstrap 3.